# How many items in a dictionary share the same value in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way to see how many items in a dictionary share the same value in Python?

Let's say that I have a dictionary like:

```
{"a": 600, "b": 75, "c": 75, "d": 90}
```

I'd like to get a resulting dictionary like:

```
{600: 1, 75: 2, 90: 1}
```

My first naive attempt would be to just use a nested-for loop and for each value then I would iterate over the dictionary again. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use itertools.groupby for this.

```
import itertools
x = {"a": 600, "b": 75, "c": 75, "d": 90}
[(k, len(list(v))) for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(x.values()))]
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks WoLpH, but I had to adjust it to use a dictionary instead: {k: len(list(v)) for k, v in itertools.groupby(x.values())}

Comment: Won't work in the general case without **sorting** those values!  E.g. with the `sorted` Python built-in function.

Answer (score 2):

When Python 2.7 comes out you can use its [collections.Counter class](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

otherwise see [counter receipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/)

Under Python 2.7a3

```
from collections import Counter
items = {"a": 600, "b": 75, "c": 75, "d": 90}    
c = Counter( items )

print(  dict( c.items() ) )
```

output is

> {600: 1, 90: 1, 75: 2}

Comment: py 3.1 is already out and there is no need to repost exactly the same answer few times a day.

Comment: @SilentGhost, Py 3.1 is out, but 2.7 isn't (still alpha) -- and as long as people post questions obviously requiring Counter it's perfectly fine to point them to it!

Comment: @Alex: it's a duplicate of a duplicate that had duplicate answer given in each thread by the same user. rather than multiplying entities it's better close the question altogether.

Comment: If this question's a duplicate, why are there _zero_ votes to close it?  Attacking the _answer_ is weird, especially when you haven't even given one "vote to close" for the question (and neither has anybody else, I note!-).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = {"a": 600, "b": 75, "c": 75, "d": 90}
>>> b = {}
>>> for k,v in a.iteritems():
...     b[v] = b.get(v,0) + 1
...
>>> b
{600: 1, 90: 1, 75: 2}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#counter-objects) (2.7+, see below at link for implementations for older versions) along with `dict.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = {"a": 600, "b": 75, "c": 75, "d": 90}
>>> d={}
>>> for v in a.values():
...   if not v in d: d[v]=1
...   else: d[v]+=1
...
>>> d
{600: 1, 90: 1, 75: 2}
```