# Python 2.7 Counting number of dictionary items with given value

Tags: python, dictionary

first question here, so i will get right to it:

using python 2.7

I have a dictionary of items, the keys are an x,y coordinate represented as a tuple: (x,y) and all the values are Boolean values.

I am trying to figure out a quick and clean method of getting a count of how many items have a given value. I do NOT need to know which keys have the given value, just how many.

there is a similar post here:
[How many items in a dictionary share the same value in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393902/how-many-items-in-a-dictionary-share-the-same-value-in-python), however I do not need a dictionary returned, just an integer.

My first thought is to iterate over the items and test each one while keeping a count of each True value or something. I am just wondering, since I am still new to python and don't know all the libraries, if there is a better/faster/simpler way to do this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This first part is mostly for fun -- I probably wouldn't use it in my code.

```
sum(d.values())
```

will  get the number of `True` values.  (Of course, you can get the number of `False` values by `len(d) - sum(d.values())`).

---

Slightly more generally, you can do something like:

```
sum(1 for x in d.values() if some_condition(x))
```

In this case, `if x` works just fine in place of `if some_condition(x)` and is what most people would use in real-world code)

**OF THE THREE SOLUTIONS I HAVE POSTED HERE, THE ABOVE IS THE MOST IDIOMATIC AND IS THE ONE I WOULD RECOMMEND**

---

Finally, I suppose this could be written a little more cleverly:

```
sum( x == chosen_value for x in d.values() )
```

This is in the same vein as my first (fun) solution as it relies on the fact that `True + True == 2`.  Clever isn't always better.  I think most people would consider this version to be a little more obscure than the one above (and therefore worse).

Comment: great. that is exactly what i wanted.

i would upvote but i can't because its my first post and i have no rep. i think i marked the answer helpful though :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey you had a valid answer though - you should have left it :)

Comment: I still prefer `sum(1 for i in something if i)` though... (and what are you doing with `==True` @mgilson) !?

Comment: just out of curiosity, why wouldn't you use the first example: sum(d.values()) in your code?

Comment: @JonClements I was trying to think of a way to make it a bit different - I'll repost with an inferior (but slightly different!) approach :)

Comment: @jguerra -- It doesn't generalize well to other conditions.  It also really limits your values to booleans or `1` and `0` which is unpythonic.

Comment: @JonClements -- Sorry, I was playing around a little  0:^) -- I've added (hopefully very clearly) which version I think is the best.  On the other hand, while I do think it's the best answer there, I've never really liked the `sum(1 for _ in ... if ...)` idiom.  It just seems like it's too round-about, but it is definitely the most common.

Comment: @mgilson what is grinding is `if i == True` :( either `i is True` or `i` :)

Comment: @JonClements -- Oh, I see what you're saying now ... well I wanted to put something in there that would generalize nicely to arbitrary conditional expressions for the benefit of OP.  You're absolutely correct that the `== True` is completely unnecessary for this example.

Answer (score 11):

If you want a data structure that you can quickly access to check the counts, you could try using a Counter (as @mgilson points out, this relies on the values themselves being hashable):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {(1, 2): 2, (3, 1): 2, (4, 4): 1, (5, 6): 4}
>>> Counter(d.values())
Counter({2: 2, 1: 1, 4: 1})
```

You could then plug in a value and get the number of times it appeared:

```
>>> c = Counter(d.values())
>>> c[2]
2
>>> c[4]
1
```