# print statement won't print value of my variable

Tags: python

so I have this code to calculate the value of the variable chance and print it there are no error codes but when it gets to the print statement no matter what compiler I use to compile it nothing appears in the output

There is no error so I don't have anything to go off of

```
import math

luck = 54
justice = 0
compassion = 1
bravery = 1
truth = 2
coreType = "Legendary"
baseChance = 0.01
element = "Light"

import math
valid = True
if coreType == "Common":
    coreRarity = 1
elif coreType == "Rare":
    coreRarity = 1.5
elif coreType == "Legendary":
    coreRarity = 3
else:
    print("Invalid core type")
    valid = False

if justice > compassion and justice > truth and justice > bravery:
    idea = "justice"
elif compassion > justice and compassion > truth and compassion > bravery:
    idea = "compassion"
elif truth > compassion and truth > justice and truth > bravery:
    idea = truth
elif bravery > compassion and bravery > truth and bravery > justice:
    idea = "bravery"
else:
    idea = "all"

if idea == "justice" and (element == "Light" or element == "Shadow"):
    boost = justice
elif idea == "truth" and (element == "Ice" or element == "Wind"):
    boost = truth
elif idea == "compassion" and (element == "Earth" or element == "Lightning"):
    boost = compassion
elif idea == "bravery" and (element == "Fire" or element == "Water"):
    boost = bravery
elif idea == "all":
    boost = bravery #basicly the above determines what the highest idea is and sets it but if the highest is all it means they are all the same so It doesn't matter one one the boost's value is cause its all the same

if valid == True:
    chance = math.max(math.sqrt(luck*0.01*1.3)+0.95,1)*0.01*(0.01*(100+5*idea)*coreRarity*baseChance)
    if coreType == "common":
        chance =* 0.25
    print(chance)
```

It's supposed to print the value of chance but prints nothing

Comment: You should get an error `AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'max'`.

Comment: @carcigenicate That is reasonable to think, however, then "Invalid core type" should be printed.

Comment: 1. `chance =* 0.25` is a syntax error, perhaps do `chance *= 0.25` 2. replace `math.max` with `max`

Comment: What do you mean by `no matter what compiler I use`? You should use the python interpreter, what else are you using?

Comment: just a suggestion, you could make `coreRarity` into a dictionary look up.

Comment: the line `idea = truth` I think is supposed to be `idea = "truth"` also

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues with your code:

- `chance =* 0.25` should be `chance *= 0.25` ([here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/assignment_operators_example.htm) is a list of all assignmet operators)
- the module `math` doesn't have a `max` attribute, so I would recommend you trying `max()` instead of `math.max()`

That beeing said try replacing your current `if` statement (the one at the end) with this one:

```
if valid == True:
    chance = max(math.sqrt(luck*0.01*1.3)+0.95,1)*0.01*(0.01*(100+5*idea)*coreRarity*baseChance)
    if coreType == "common":
        chance *= 0.25
    print(chance)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways this code can be improved:

**Setting coreRarity** - 
This code below:

```
valid = True
if coreType == "Common":
    coreRarity = 1
elif coreType == "Rare":
    coreRarity = 1.5
elif coreType == "Legendary":
    coreRarity = 3
else:
    print("Invalid core type")
    valid = False
```

can be made into a dictionary lookup

```
coreRarityDict = {
    "Common": 1,
    "Rare": 1.5,
    "Legendary": 3
}
```

To set `valid` and `coreRarity` uses readable dictionary methods

```
valid = coreType in coreRarityDict
if valid:
    coreRarity = coreRarityDict[coreType] # dictionary lookup
else:
    print("Invalid core type")
```

**Setting idea** - The next part:

```
if justice > compassion and justice > truth and justice > bravery:
    idea = "justice"
elif compassion > justice and compassion > truth and compassion > bravery:
    idea = "compassion"
elif truth > compassion and truth > justice and truth > bravery:
    idea = truth
elif bravery > compassion and bravery > truth and bravery > justice:
    idea = "bravery"
else:
    idea = "all"
```

The logic here is basically boils down to which is the (strict) maximum of `justice, compassion, truth, bravery`. If there is a ties for the maximum, set idea to "all".
Note `idea = truth` looks like it should be `idea = "truth"`

Again let's use a dictionary

```
ideasDict = {
    "justice": justice,
    "compassion": compassion,
    "truth": truth,
    "bravery": bravery, 
}
```

To set idea we want the key with the strict largest value
See - [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

```
idea = max(ideasDict, key=lambda x: ideasDict[x])
```

To check for ties we can count the number of times this idea value occurs in our dictionary - see [Python 2.7 Counting number of dictionary items with given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462365/python-2-7-counting-number-of-dictionary-items-with-given-value)

```
sum(1 for x in ideasDict.values() if x == idea)
```

Combining this,

```
idea = max(ideasDict, key=lambda x: ideasDict[x])
idea_freq = sum(1 for x in ideasDict.values() if x == idea)
if idea_freq > 1:
    idea = "all"
```

**Setting boost** - This code

```
if idea == "justice" and (element == "Light" or element == "Shadow"):
    boost = justice
elif idea == "truth" and (element == "Ice" or element == "Wind"):
    boost = truth
elif idea == "compassion" and (element == "Earth" or element == "Lightning"):
    boost = compassion
elif idea == "bravery" and (element == "Fire" or element == "Water"):
    boost = bravery
elif idea == "all":
    boost = bravery #basically the above determines what the highest idea is and sets it but if the highest is all it means they are all the same so It doesn't matter one one the boost's value is cause its all the same
```

Notice you are repeating `if idea == "xx": boost = xx`
Reusing the dictionary the code would look like

```
if idea == "justice" and (element == "Light" or element == "Shadow"):
    boost = ideasDict[idea]
elif idea == "truth" and (element == "Ice" or element == "Wind"):
    boost = ideasDict[idea]
elif idea == "compassion" and (element == "Earth" or element == "Lightning"):
    boost = ideasDict[idea]
elif idea == "bravery" and (element == "Fire" or element == "Water"):
    boost = ideasDict[idea]
elif idea == "all":
    boost = bravery #basically the above determines what the highest idea is and sets it but if the highest is all it means they are all the same so It doesn't matter one one the boost's value is cause its all the same
```

That's a lot of repeating `boost = ideasDict[idea]`! Let's simplify further! Note the `elif` can just be made as an `if` as your conditions are non-overlapping: `idea` can't be both `== "justice"` and `== "truth"`. Let's use a dictionary again

```
elementsBoostDict = {
    "justice": ["Light", "Shadow"],
    "compassion": ["Ice", "Wind"],
    "truth": ["Earth", "Lightning"],
    "bravery": ["Fire", "Water"], 
}

if idea == "all":
    boost = bravery
elif element in elementsBoostDict[idea]:
    boost = ideasDict[idea]
```

Notice `boost` may not be set e.g `idea == "justice"` and `element == "ice"` and `boost` is not used anywhere else in your code? Is this intended?

**Calculating chance** - this is your code

```
if valid == True:
    chance = math.max(math.sqrt(luck*0.01*1.3)+0.95,1)*0.01*(0.01*(100+5*idea)*coreRarity*baseChance)
    if coreType == "common":
        chance =* 0.25
    print(chance)
```

Note `idea` is a string (I get error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` after previously correcting to `idea = "truth"`) and should be replaced by it's relative value.

The line `if valid == True:` can be simplified to `if valid:`
Your chance calculation includes a lot of hard coded numbers and can be simplified `0.01*0.01 = 0.0001`. Let's move this into a function with some defaults. Also as `luck` is a percentage we'll use `luck=0.54` and remove the multiplication by `0.01`.

```
def chance_calc(coreType, coreRarity, idea, luck=0.54, baseChance=0.01):
    temp  = math.max(math.sqrt(luck * 1.3) + 0.95, 1)
    chance = temp * 0.0001 * (100 + 5 * ideasDict[idea]) * coreRarity * baseChance
    if coreType == "common":
        chance *= 0.25
    return chance
```

**Final code**

```
import math

justice = 0
compassion = 1
bravery = 1
truth = 2
coreType = "Legendary"
element = "Light"

coreRarityDict = {
    "Common": 1,
    "Rare": 1.5,
    "Legendary": 3
}

ideasDict= {
    "justice": justice,
    "compassion": compassion,
    "truth": truth,
    "bravery": bravery, 
}

elementsBoost = {
    "justice": ["Light", "Shadow"],
    "compassion": ["Ice", "Wind"],
    "truth": ["Earth", "Lightning"],
    "bravery": ["Fire", "Water"], 
}

# set coreRarity
valid = coreType in coreRarityDict
if valid:
    coreRarity = coreRarityDict[coreType]
else:
    print("Invalid core type")

# set idea
idea = max(ideasDict, key=lambda x: ideasDict[x])
idea_freq = sum(1 for x in ideasDict.values() if x == idea)
if idea_freq > 1:
    idea = "all"

# set boost
if idea == "all":
    boost = bravery
elif element in elementsBoost[idea]:
    boost = ideasDict[idea]

def chance_calc(coreType, coreRarity, idea, luck=0.54, baseChance=0.01):
    temp  = math.max(math.sqrt(luck * 1.3) + 0.95, 1)
    chance = temp * 0.0001 * (100 + 5 * ideasDict[idea]) * coreRarity * baseChance
    if coreType == "common":
        chance *= 0.25
    return chance

if valid:
    chance = chance_calc(coreType, coreRarity, idea)
    print(chance)

# result 0.0005899919528666251
```

**Final thoughts and post mortem**

There's a high chance I changed what you intended or made some error.

Using a structured data type like a dictionary has the benefit of simplifying code and provides methods we can use. An alternative could be using classes which could combine `ideasDict` and `elementsBoost`.

If idea is "all" then `ideasDict[idea]` will return `None` and `chance_calc` will return an error.

`boost` is not used

If `ideasDict[idea]` is big enough the chance may be bigger than 1.

The chance calculation looks like it could be improved. A good idea might be to write down a bunch of combinations of `justice, compassion, bravery, truth, coreType, element` and what chance you would like for each and then try to write a function that gets close to this.